# don't understand difference between plugin and script

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm new to programming. I'm actually working with php, javascript, jquery... also have a bootstrap template which has many scripts and plugins.

I know how to use scripts and plugins, but im kinda doing it with my eyes closed. I've searched on the internet the differences between a script and a plugin, but i can't seem to understand quite well..

Comment: As far as JavaScript goes, a script/plugin would probably be the same thing. Usually we call them JavaScript libraries/frameworks rather than plugins. Plugins are usually application specific, for a built solution such as Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla, etc. where you are using a prebuilt system and may customize with PHP/JS/jQuery etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a plugin would be something that uses a library's API, jQuery ( a library ) for instance opens up it's own API that is built upon javascript. A jQuery plugin uses those API's to do things. Such as an Image Slider plugin. That image slider plugin would use jQuery calls to make things happen, which in reality is just javascript at the end of the day.

A script is the foundation of those plugins, you can also have vanilla javascript plugins, which act just as a jQuery plugin but execute without jQuery.

You will notice in bootstrap it requires jQuery in order to function properly. This is because bootstrap makes use of the jQuery API to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Just think of a script as the chasis of the car and the plugins as all of the features that the car has on it.

Comment: more accurate would be, 'think of the *framework* as the chassis of the car, and the plugins as the features' since both the framework (jquery) and plugins (jquery-file-upload) are scripts